# Configure correctly session cakephp

Tags: session, cakephp

I have a site developed with cakephp 2.3
I have a system of login and after some minutes (about 2) of inactivity the system logout me.

Into my core.php I have this line:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'my_app',
    'timeout' => 4320
));

    Configure::write('Security.level', 'medium');
```

I have tried many solution to set `timeout`, `high level`, `checkUserAgent`, nothing works after a few minutes logout me.
To test it I use Chrome

How can I solve it?

Comment: The classic reason for "I get logged out" is 404 requests for image, js, css files invalidating the session - Check for missing assets.

Comment: @AD7six Thanks for that. Didn't know about that "common problem". Nice to know.

Comment: Ok in facts I thought that, but how to check them? with firebug and Chrome debugger I haven't found any errors @AD7six

Comment: They'll show up in the apache logs, in the application error log, and in the network tab. If it's not that, you'll likely need to debug the CakeSession class (put log statements in it) because setting the session timeout to 3 days (deliberate?) will mean your session is being invalidated by something. a good idea to test with 'cake' defaults to eliminate the possibility that something is deleting the session files.

Comment: Into my application in error.log there is an error: doesn't find JSController, I think that is the problem but I don't know which file and where.. isn't easy to find @AD7six

Comment: you mean except for the message `Request URL: /js/foo.js` which is right under that :P?

Comment: I expected that but... I'm not lucky... :) @AD7six

Comment: @AD7six , why 404 requests for images, js and etc invalidating the session?

Comment: I think that is return a 404 error the core try to make a call to a controller like JSController (if missing file is a javascript) and is certainly that this controller doesn't exist and allow permission of auth logout you for security I think @Vadim

Comment: That's not the reason. If there are concurrent requests and one of the "other" requests uses the session and [renews the session](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php#L638) it's very easy for the the session id to get out of sync with the server and hence "log you out". I.e. if events occur in this order: request for page, request for 404, return from 404 (new session id in headers, session regenerated), return from page (previous session id in headers) - the session has been lost.

Comment: @AD7six, why return from 404 will generate new session id?  You mean that such behaviour coded for security.level = 'high' or this true for all security levels?

Comment: I recommend you let cake handle the sessions instead of php. Better GC